# How to visualize entities predicted by NER model?

Tags: python, spacy, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

How do I visualize entities predicted by a Bert-like model that's built using Pytorch?

I built a NER model using Bert. My model works fine. It returns a list of predicted entities:

**example :**

```
evaluate_one_text(model, 'functional scores for subjects, as assessed by Knee Injury and Osteoarthritis Outcome Score PRO (KOOS)')
```

**which returns :** the sentence + the predicted entities

```
 "functional scores for subjects, as assessed by Knee Injury and Osteoarthritis Outcome Score PRO (KOOS)"
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-PRO', 'I-PRO', 'I-PRO', 'I-PRO', 'I-PRO', 'I-PRO', 'I-PRO', 'O', 'I-PRO', 'O']
```

is there a way to visualize this ? something like spacy's displacy maybe? but I can't see how go from this to a DOC object from spacy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpaCy and displacy for this.

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

# prepare data
nlp = spacy.blank('en')
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab,
          words=['Peter', 'Parker', 'went', 'to', 'Berlin', '.'],
          spaces=[True, True, True, True, True, False])
# this means this is the tokenized version of: 'Peter Parker went to Berlin.' 
# in this case all tokens have spaces behind them except the last.

# prepare annotations in format (start_character, end_character, label)
annotations_char_spans = [(0, 12, 'fictional character'), (21, 27, 'location')]

# add custom entities to SpaCy doc object
custom_entitites = []
for span_start, span_end, label in annotations_char_spans:
    ent = doc.char_span(span_start, span_end, label=label)
    if ent is None:
        continue
    custom_entitites.append(ent)
doc.ents = custom_entitites

# display (open localhost:5000 in your browser)
options = {"ents": ['fictional character', 'location'],
           "colors": {'fictional character': "#85C1E9", "location": "#FF6961"}}
displacy.serve(doc, style="ent", host="localhost", port=5000, options=options)
```

Which will give you:

[image]

So what you still need to do is tokenize the text using the exact tokenizer used for label creation (so your model tokenizer) and then calculate the label character start and end indices. You will probably have to iteratively sum up over the token lengths + whether there is a space behind them and set the start from the first character of the "B-" part of the entity until the first letter after the last "I-" part of the entity.

Note that the `if ent is None` part means any token span not exactly matching a token span in `doc` defined by `words` and `spaces` will be skipped and not annotated.